# Unexpected CSS Grid behaviour

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a layout for the form, see attached code snippet. You can notice that output result is different from "layout" in `grid-template-areas`. For example, on the second row `email` and `address1` should be split in the middle, in fact they are divided on 1/3 mark or so.

I also noticed that visual bug in the gaps, but I don't see anything wrong in the html part.

[image: gap bug]

I'll welcome any ideas on what caused such issues in my grid.

```css
.grid {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'firstName firstName firstName lastName lastName lastName shares shares'
  'email email email email address1 address1 address1 address1'
  'phone phone phone phone city city state zip';
  gap: 2px;
}

.f {
  grid-area: firstName;
}

.l {
  grid-area: lastName;
}

.s {
  grid-area: shares;
}

.e {
  grid-area: email;
}

.a {
  grid-area: address1;
}

.p {
  grid-area: phone;
}

.c {
  grid-area: city;
}

.st {
  grid-area: state;
}

.z {
  grid-area: zip;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input type="text" class="f">
  <input type="text" class="l">
  <input type="text" class="s">
  <input type="text" class="e">
  <input type="text" class="a">
  <input type="text" class="p">
  <input type="text" class="c">
  <input type="text" class="st">
  <input type="text" class="z">
</div>
```

Comment: first name is taking 3 columns while email is taking 4 so it's logical. Make both of them take the same number of columns (also add width:100% to all your inputs)

Comment: your columns don't match , remove the gap  and set  margin `input {margin:1px;}` instead and mismatch from columns won't show.

Comment: @TemaniAfif is there any rule for that? I haven't seen in docs, that columns must match. It was intentional by me to make the layout, where first row divided by 3 parts of same width, and second by 2.

Comment: well, no need to have a rule. Draw your grid and place the element and you will logically see they don't match. an element taking 3 columns cannot be equal to another taking 4. Maybe 8 columns isn't suitable for your case, find a better number where you can have same number of columns with a different division

Comment: @TemaniAfif 8 columns fits this grid great on a paper. first row 3-3-2 (8), second 4-4, last one 4-2-1-1. My question is if it's invalid for css grid exactly? I can build this stuff perfectly with flexbox, just wondering why grid doesn't allow me to do that

Comment: 3 col on the first row, then 4 on the second row for the imputs, with the gap set, you obviously sees that firstname and email do not span the same numbers of columns ....

Comment: @G-Cyrillus so you say that in CSS grid columns can't have different widths on different Rows? Could you attach a link to MSDN rule to your answer and I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: *CSS grid columns can't have different widths on different Rows?* --> if it was the case, we can no more call it a grid

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see a working examples of grids with different widths and even heights https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid-area_named4

Comment: Why don't you try to use ```grid-template-columns```, instead of ```grid-template-areas```? It could help you to redefine your grid. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner thanks, actually i was using it, but then switched to areas for simplicity. I know that's hilarious, since it made thinks more complex in result, as guys says above that if you have areas, you can't have various grid cells.

Comment: no, they are not. They are taking different number of columns/rows BUT the columns should be equal between rows (inspect the code using chrome to notice this)

Comment: can you count the areas in my css rule? they are all 8. Each row has 8 cells. Different areas can take from 1 to 4 cells width, but their sum is always 8.

Comment: And in your case, one is taking 3 and another is taking 4. why you expect them to be equal? this is creating the mismatch you have. To avoid it, they need to take the same number

Comment: I don't expect them to be equal, please read my question. I am expecting them to take space that I specified in the rule. If it's a hard layout to read, just notice second row. It should be 4 columns of email and 4 of address, in the output, they are not equally divided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **explicitely** define column size or they will get an auto width based on the content. You also need to make your input full width of each area or they will also keep their default size:

```css
.grid {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns:1fr; /* equal width columns */
  grid-template-areas: 
  'firstName firstName firstName lastName lastName lastName shares shares'
  'email email email email address1 address1 address1 address1'
  'phone phone phone phone city city state zip';
  gap: 2px;
}
input {
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.f {
  grid-area: firstName;
}

.l {
  grid-area: lastName;
}

.s {
  grid-area: shares;
}

.e {
  grid-area: email;
}

.a {
  grid-area: address1;
}

.p {
  grid-area: phone;
}

.c {
  grid-area: city;
}

.st {
  grid-area: state;
}

.z {
  grid-area: zip;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input type="text" class="f">
  <input type="text" class="l">
  <input type="text" class="s">
  <input type="text" class="e">
  <input type="text" class="a">
  <input type="text" class="p">
  <input type="text" class="c">
  <input type="text" class="st">
  <input type="text" class="z">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. And you can see now, that even with different cells sizes, it's still a grid :) I never knew about grid-auto-columns rule before.

Comment: @flppv different size element but always same size columns ;)

Comment: Yeah, just like in my initial setup. always 8 columns. Thanks again, it was helpful! Just one little rule that redefined the whole layout!